# Get uri in PHP extension

Tags: php, php-extension

I am writing a PHP extension to analyse web request. In order to do that I need to get request URI. So far i have been using SG(request_info).request_uri to achieve this task but there is a problem with this approach.

When RewriteRule is enforced in .htaccess file then i always get the rewritten URI.

for example :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

With above `RewriteRule` enforced, if URI `http://localhost/test/public/articles` is executed then URI is rewritten as `/test/public/index.php` and so is the value of `SG(request_info).request_uri` but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` still has the value "/test/public/articles".

So my question here is how can I get the original URI i.e. the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in extension ?